# Why use morris traversal not recursion in binary tree or binary search tree?

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I am learning data structures, i am wondering why not use recursion but morris traversal. Both of them have O(n) time complexity and O(1) extra space.

Comment: That is only true if you are able to do tail recursion. [This talk](https://youtu.be/YA-nB2wjVcI?t=695) (right before the 12 minute-mark) has a in my opinion very good explanation on the algorithm and what its advantages are